# Turtlebot3 gazebo simulation not loading in ros2 humble

Tags: ros2, simulation, ros-humble, turtlebot-gazebo

Just updated to ROS2 Humble and Ubuntu 22.04,
Went through all the setup instructions for both ROS2 humble and Turtlebot3,

**ROS2 humble and Gazebo Classic**

This is the error that is occurring,

```
[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /home/zorx/.ros/log/2023-11-15-19-13-16-666336-zorx-48737
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
urdf_file_name : turtlebot3_waffle_pi.urdf
urdf_file_name : turtlebot3_waffle_pi.urdf
[INFO] [gzserver-1]: process started with pid [48738]
[INFO] [gzclient-2]: process started with pid [48740]
[INFO] [robot_state_publisher-3]: process started with pid [48742]
[INFO] [spawn_entity.py-4]: process started with pid [48744]
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1700055797.383270144] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment base_footprint
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1700055797.383338670] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment base_link
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1700055797.383343727] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment base_scan
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1700055797.383346669] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment camera_link
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1700055797.383349388] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment camera_rgb_frame
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1700055797.383352226] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment camera_rgb_optical_frame
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1700055797.383355080] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment caster_back_left_link
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1700055797.383357847] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment caster_back_right_link
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1700055797.383360588] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment imu_link
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1700055797.383363294] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment wheel_left_link
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1700055797.383366170] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment wheel_right_link
[spawn_entity.py-4] [INFO] [1700055797.608546486] [spawn_entity]: Spawn Entity started
[spawn_entity.py-4] [INFO] [1700055797.608755151] [spawn_entity]: Loading entity XML from file /home/zorx/Desktop/tb3_ws/install/turtlebot3_gazebo/share/turtlebot3_gazebo/models/turtlebot3_waffle_pi/model.sdf
[spawn_entity.py-4] [INFO] [1700055797.609309410] [spawn_entity]: Waiting for service /spawn_entity, timeout = 30
[spawn_entity.py-4] [INFO] [1700055797.609487792] [spawn_entity]: Waiting for service /spawn_entity
[spawn_entity.py-4] [ERROR] [1700055827.665935221] [spawn_entity]: Service %s/spawn_entity unavailable. Was Gazebo started with GazeboRosFactory?
[spawn_entity.py-4] [ERROR] [1700055827.666978495] [spawn_entity]: Spawn service failed. Exiting.
[ERROR] [spawn_entity.py-4]: process has died [pid 48744, exit code 1, cmd '/opt/ros/humble/lib/gazebo_ros/spawn_entity.py -entity waffle_pi -file /home/zorx/Desktop/tb3_ws/install/turtlebot3_gazebo/share/turtlebot3_gazebo/models/turtlebot3_waffle_pi/model.sdf -x 0.0 -y 0.0 -z 0.01 --ros-args'].
^C[WARNING] [launch]: user interrupted with ctrl-c (SIGINT)
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1700055838.792738296] [rclcpp]: signal_handler(signum=2)
[gzserver-1] [INFO] [1700055838.793474120] [rclcpp]: signal_handler(signum=2)
[ERROR] [gzclient-2]: process has died [pid 48740, exit code -2, cmd 'gzclient'].
[INFO] [robot_state_publisher-3]: process has finished cleanly [pid 48742]
^C[WARNING] [launch]: user interrupted with ctrl-c (SIGINT) again, ignoring...
[gzserver-1] [INFO] [1700055839.056530545] [rclcpp]: signal_handler(signum=2)
^C[WARNING] [launch]: user interrupted with ctrl-c (SIGINT) again, ignoring...
[gzserver-1] [INFO] [1700055839.272136691] [rclcpp]: signal_handler(signum=2)
[ERROR] [gzserver-1]: process[gzserver-1] failed to terminate '5' seconds after receiving 'SIGINT', escalating to 'SIGTERM'
[INFO] [gzserver-1]: sending signal 'SIGTERM' to process[gzserver-1]
[gzserver-1] [INFO] [1700055843.802515876] [rclcpp]: signal_handler(signum=15)
[ERROR] [gzserver-1]: process[gzserver-1] failed to terminate '10.0' seconds after receiving 'SIGTERM', escalating to 'SIGKILL'
[INFO] [gzserver-1]: sending signal 'SIGKILL' to process[gzserver-1]
[ERROR] [gzserver-1]: process has died [pid 48738, exit code -9, cmd 'gzserver /home/zorx/Desktop/tb3_ws/install/turtlebot3_gazebo/share/turtlebot3_gazebo/worlds/empty_world.world -slibgazebo_ros_init.so -slibgazebo_ros_factory.so -slibgazebo_ros_force_system.so'].
```

These are env variables in my **.bashrc**

```
source /opt/ros/humble/setup.bash
export TURTLEBOT3_MODEL=waffle_pi
export GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH=$GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH:/opt/ros/humble/share/turtlebot3_gazebo/models
```

Any fix?

Answer (score 0):

> [spawn_entity.py-4] [ERROR] [1700055827.665935221] [spawn_entity]: Service %s/spawn_entity unavailable. Was Gazebo started with GazeboRosFactory?

That usually points to needing to execute the gazebo process with the ROS factory SO

https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/blob/main/nav2_bringup/launch/tb3_simulation_launch.py#L175-L186

```
    start_gazebo_server_cmd = ExecuteProcess(
        condition=IfCondition(use_simulator),
        cmd=[
            'gzserver',
            '-s',
            'libgazebo_ros_init.so',
            '-s',
            'libgazebo_ros_factory.so',
            world,
        ],
        cwd=[launch_dir],
        output='screen',
    )
```