# Turtlebot3 not loading in gazebo (ROS2 Galactic, Gazebo-11)

Tags: turtlebot3, python3, errors, ros2-launch, ros-galactic

I am trying to load a Turtlebot 3 waffle in the house world, get its laser scan data in Rviz2 and then navigate to 3 checkpoints with the help of rviz2 after mapping the world. The commands I am using for the laser scan visualisation are `ros2 launch turtlebot3_gazebo turtlebot3_house.launch.py` and `ros2 launch turtlebot3_bringup rviz2.launch.py`. However, the world gets loaded without the bot, and then I press Ctrl+C.

```bash
[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /home/sdhar/.ros/log/2024-03-24-23-49-25-573030-sdhar-Inspiron-3593-3376
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
urdf_file_name : turtlebot3_waffle_pi.urdf
[INFO] [gzserver-1]: process started with pid [3378]
[INFO] [gzclient   -2]: process started with pid [3380]
[INFO] [robot_state_publisher-3]: process started with pid [3383]
[INFO] [spawn_entity.py-4]: process started with pid [3386]
[robot_state_publisher-3] 1711304366.132554 [0] robot_stat: selected interface "lo" is not multicast-capable: disabling multicast
[robot_state_publisher-3] Link base_link had 7 children
[robot_state_publisher-3] Link camera_link had 1 children
[robot_state_publisher-3] Link camera_rgb_frame had 1 children
[robot_state_publisher-3] Link camera_rgb_optical_frame had 0 children
[robot_state_publisher-3] Link caster_back_left_link had 0 children
[robot_state_publisher-3] Link caster_back_right_link had 0 children
[robot_state_publisher-3] Link imu_link had 0 children
[robot_state_publisher-3] Link base_scan had 0 children
[robot_state_publisher-3] Link wheel_left_link had 0 children
[robot_state_publisher-3] Link wheel_right_link had 0 children
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1711304366.140797746] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment base_footprint
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1711304366.140914141] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment base_link
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1711304366.140924386] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment base_scan
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1711304366.140930400] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment camera_link
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1711304366.140936128] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment camera_rgb_frame
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1711304366.140941833] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment camera_rgb_optical_frame
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1711304366.140947691] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment caster_back_left_link
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1711304366.140953421] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment caster_back_right_link
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1711304366.140958992] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment imu_link
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1711304366.140964769] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment wheel_left_link
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1711304366.140970402] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment wheel_right_link
[gzserver-1] 1711304366.443399 [0]   gzserver: selected interface "lo" is not multicast-capable: disabling multicast
[spawn_entity.py-4] 1711304366.509809 [0]    python3: selected interface "lo" is not multicast-capable: disabling multicast
[spawn_entity.py-4] [INFO] [1711304366.565038549] [spawn_entity]: Spawn Entity started
[spawn_entity.py-4] [INFO] [1711304366.565411068] [spawn_entity]: Loading entity XML from file /opt/ros/galactic/share/turtlebot3_gazebo/models/turtlebot3_waffle_pi/model.sdf
[spawn_entity.py-4] [INFO] [1711304366.566600601] [spawn_entity]: Waiting for service /spawn_entity, timeout = 5
[spawn_entity.py-4] [INFO] [1711304366.566910553] [spawn_entity]: Waiting for service /spawn_entity
[gzserver-1] Warning [parser.cc:833] XML Attribute[version] in element[sdf] not defined in SDF, ignoring.
[gzserver-1] Couldn't find a preferred IP via the getifaddrs() call; I'm assuming that your IP address is 127.0.0.1.  This should work for local processes, but will almost certainly not work if you have remote processes.Report to the disc-zmq development team to seek a fix.
[gzserver-1] Couldn't find a preferred IP via the getifaddrs() call; I'm assuming that your IP address is 127.0.0.1.  This should work for local processes, but will almost certainly not work if you have remote processes.Report to the disc-zmq development team to seek a fix.
[gzserver-1] Couldn't find a preferred IP via the getifaddrs() call; I'm assuming that your IP address is 127.0.0.1.  This should work for local processes, but will almost certainly not work if you have remote processes.Report to the disc-zmq development team to seek a fix.
[gzserver-1] Couldn't find a preferred IP via the getifaddrs() call; I'm assuming that your IP address is 127.0.0.1.  This should work for local processes, but will almost certainly not work if you have remote processes.Report to the disc-zmq development team to seek a fix.
[gzclient   -2] Couldn't find a preferred IP via the getifaddrs() call; I'm assuming that your IP address is 127.0.0.1.  This should work for local processes, but will almost certainly not work if you have remote processes.Report to the disc-zmq development team to seek a fix.
[gzclient   -2] Couldn't find a preferred IP via the getifaddrs() call; I'm assuming that your IP address is 127.0.0.1.  This should work for local processes, but will almost certainly not work if you have remote processes.Report to the disc-zmq development team to seek a fix.
[gzclient   -2] Couldn't find a preferred IP via the getifaddrs() call; I'm assuming that your IP address is 127.0.0.1.  This should work for local processes, but will almost certainly not work if you have remote processes.Report to the disc-zmq development team to seek a fix.
[gzclient   -2] Couldn't find a preferred IP via the getifaddrs() call; I'm assuming that your IP address is 127.0.0.1.  This should work for local processes, but will almost certainly not work if you have remote processes.Report to the disc-zmq development team to seek a fix.
[spawn_entity.py-4] [INFO] [1711304367.572218805] [spawn_entity]: Calling service /spawn_entity
[gzclient   -2] 
[gzclient   -2] libcurl: (6) Could not resolve host: fuel.gazebosim.org
[gzclient   -2] 
[gzclient   -2] libcurl: (6) Could not resolve host: fuel.ignitionrobotics.org
[spawn_entity.py-4] [INFO] [1711304377.911090795] [spawn_entity]: Spawn status: Entity pushed to spawn queue, but spawn service timed outwaiting for entity to appear in simulation under the name [waffle_pi]
[spawn_entity.py-4] [ERROR] [1711304377.911732145] [spawn_entity]: Spawn service failed. Exiting.
[ERROR] [spawn_entity.py-4]: process has died [pid 3386, exit code 1, cmd '/opt/ros/galactic/lib/gazebo_ros/spawn_entity.py -entity waffle_pi -file /opt/ros/galactic/share/turtlebot3_gazebo/models/turtlebot3_waffle_pi/model.sdf -x -2.0 -y -0.5 -z 0.01 --ros-args'].
[INFO] [gzclient   -2]: process has finished cleanly [pid 3380]
^C[WARNING] [launch]: user interrupted with ctrl-c (SIGINT)
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1711304381.589692874] [rclcpp]: signal_handler(signal_value=2)
[INFO] [robot_state_publisher-3]: process has finished cleanly [pid 3383]
[ERROR] [gzserver-1]: process has died [pid 3378, exit code -2, cmd 'gzserver /opt/ros/galactic/share/turtlebot3_gazebo/worlds/turtlebot3_house.world                                                                      -s libgazebo_ros_init.so   -s libgazebo_ros_factory.so   -s libgazebo_ros_force_system.so       '].
```

I have seen a related question [here](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/105433/turtlebot3-gazebo-simulation-not-loading-in-ros2-humble) but am having trouble finding the corresponding lines in the files for ROS2 Galactic. I also saw somewhere that this needs Python 3.10 but I can't find Python 3.10 in `apt-cache search`. Could I get a detailed guide for these approaches or a new approach for solving this? Urgent help is required.